# Globally Register Custom Angular Material Icons (even with lazy loading modules)

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons

So I am adding custom svg icons to angular material. I do this in the app component:

```
private addCustomIcon(name: string) {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        name,
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
            `../../../assets/custom-icons/${name}.svg`
        )
    );
}
```

Everything works great, except..... I am using lazy loaded modules and inside those modules the icons do not appear unless I re-do this in the highest component in each module. Is there any way I can GLOBALLY register these icons?

Comment: Doing this from app.component.ts works fine to me; but in your case you have a wrong path to **assest**, from app.component the correct path is `../assests/..`